# A matter of taste ... and sight

Tags: cipher

```
EILBPALBENKCNALBEIKCNECDLECANALAJICBLAODPACDIECBEILB
```

As you may have guessed, the title is a crucial hint.
Is the message about taste or is it about sight ?

Hint :

> First, you'll have to cipher instead of decipher. Only then you might notice a pattern.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The message is:

> [Sometimes I dream about cheese](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/sometimes-i-dream-about-cheese)

Reasoning:

> First you translate each letter to the 5-bit encoding using a [Bacon cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacon%27s_cipher), a.k.a taste from title, then make each 5-bits a row, strip the first character, then zig zag across the columns getting letters in braille (A is blank, B is dot), a.k.a. sight from title, that spell out Sometimes I dream about cheese.

Diagram:

> [image]

Comment: I recognize this message from somewhere...

Comment: @D.Tanya the link explains where it comes from

Comment: Oops didn't notice it was a link. Thanks! D: